# Using undefined function in an expression

Tags: functions

I want to use undefined functions in expressions to be simplified. For example.

I want mathematica to simplify this input

$(f^{\prime\prime}(t),g^{\prime\prime}(t))\cdot (-g^\prime(t),f^\prime(t)) $

into  this output:

$f'(t)g''(t)- f''(t)g'(t)$.

How does one go about the "Simplify" command for that first expression in order to get the second one? How do you specify that $f$ is a function of $t$, without of course defining it, in an expression?

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at `Dot`.

Comment: he most certainly does not :P

Answer (score 4):

You can define the derivative of a function easily: D[f[t], {t, 1}] is the first derivative of the (unspecified) function f[t]. So your expression is:

```
{D[f[t], {t, 2}], D[g[t], {t, 2}]}.{-D[g[t], {t, 1}], D[f[t], {t, 1}]}
```

which nicely returns the desired expression.

You will likely benefit from exploring the documentation a little. For instance, had you looked into the docs for the derivative function by typing

```
?Derivative
```

or the simpler form

```
?D
```

you would have been able to answer your own question.

`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  My issue with the documentation was in understanding that I could input f[t] without having to define f[t] somewhere earlier in the code.